# Building Kernel Module Against: Can not find kernel header for function

Tags: build, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I have kernel modules which are built against kernel version 2.6.18. My task is to build the modules against kernel version 2.6.32.

The problem is that make command results in  **implicit declaration of function ‘MULTICAST’** error. I inspected the code and the code fragment which gives the error is as shown below:

```
MULTICAST( pkt_iph->daddr )
```

where "pkt_iph" is of type "struct iphdr". MULTICAST is defined in /linux/in.h as:

`#define MULTICAST(x)    (((x) & htonl(0xf0000000)) == htonl(0xe0000000))`

for kernel version 2.6.18. How can I replace it for 2.6.32 or is there any other solution that you could provide?

Answer (score 0):

It's replaced by `IN_MULTICAST()`, also in `linux/in.h`